# creating accdb file from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-office, c#-2.0, oledb

I want to create Ms access2007 file programatically from c# using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Comment: It's nice to know what you want to do. A proper question would explain what it is you actually need help with, including what you've already tried that doesn't work, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some example:

```
    using System;
    using ADOX;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Class1
        {
            [STAThread]
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();

                cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;");

                Console.WriteLine("Database Created Successfully");

                cat = null;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Build I have already try it and i got the message:
 "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done." My code : ADOX.CatalogClass cat = new ADOX.CatalogClass(); cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Tmp.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

Comment: Oh yahhh I Resolve it                                            cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;");    Thanks any way

Comment: Sorry for inconvinience, I also have made some changes to my code, so that it is work properly.

Comment: <Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security> for ADOX